# jquery code to submit form present non expected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In my spring project, I have this file called **sbmit.js** where I have the following code to submit all my forms:

```
$('.form').submit(function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        $("#"+data).show();

        $("#target").each (function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});

function md5() {
    var senha = $(this).val();
    $("input[name=senha").val($.md5(senha));
}
```

But when I try submit any form, by example, like that:

```
  <c:url value="/categoria/cadastra" var="cadastraCategoria"/>
  <form class="form" role="form" action="${cadastraCategoria}" method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" autofocus>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Cadastrar</button>
      </p>
  </form>

  <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success">
    <strong>Pronto!</strong> Categoria cadastrada com sucesso.
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>

  <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Erro!</strong> N&atilde;o foi possivel cadastrar a categoria.
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
```

instead of capture the response from server and use to display one of the two , the application display a blank page with this response.

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

ps.: the method in the server which receives the requisition from client have all this structure:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_categoria')")
public String cadastra(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(categoria.cadastra(request, response))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

Comment: did you debug your js ?

Comment: yes, no error is displayed in the console. and the form is submited to server and the data stored in the database, only the return don't present the expected behavior.

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` below this line `posting.done(function( data ) {` and post that value here.

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Yasser I add this line in my code, but no message is being displayed in the console.

Comment: @Barmar I put the code inside the $(document).ready() but the problem remains

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the JS code, does it get hit?

Comment: @Barma Wired, now I starting to think the application never run my code (I put the breakpoint, and don't get hit). How the form is being submitted? Maybe I should change the HTML?

Comment: Either you have a syntax error or you didn't put it into `$(document).ready()` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figure out what's happening: How I am using one unique method for all the pages, I just need change the function from:

```
$('.form').submit(function( event )
```

to:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
```

and now it's all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code says you have multiple elements with same id:

```
$("#target").each (function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

If this is the case then this is an invalid markup so you will face some unexpected behavior from browsers.

Solution to that is change ids to classNames like `class='target'` and change little in js selector `$(".target")`.

Comment: Ok, then I correct this, but the problem is still happening.